# Does Spring Cloud Feign client call execute inside hystrix command?

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix, netflix-feign

I'm configuring a sample application using this example: 
http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#spring-cloud-feign-inheritance. In this section http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#spring-cloud-ribbon it is said that:

> Feign already uses Ribbon, so if you are using @FeignClient then this
>   section also applies

Does that mean that @FeignClient uses Hystrix too? Does the call to feign client execute inside hystrix command? if so, what is the proper way to pass hystrix configuration?

There are samples that wrap calls to feign client with @HystrixCommand. Is it a correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [open ticket](https://github.com/Netflix/feign/issues/189) to support hystrix with feign. Currently, you need to wrap calls to feign clients with hystrix.

Comment: Why wouldn't this work -

[AT]HystrixCommand
 public X getX() {
   myFeignClient.getX();
        }

Comment: The open ticket has been closed. You can now use the `feign-hystrix` module. Use the `HystrixFeign.builder()` rather than the normal feign builder. All methods will be protected by a circuit. You can also return `HystrixCommand<MyObject>` if you want reactive or async support.

Comment: Hey spencergibb, thanks for quick reply.I am using spring-cloud with netflix oss. And i declared by FeignClient with FeignClient annotation. I wasn't using a Feign.builder(). Is there a way to plumb HystrixFeign instead of Feign client with annotation ? I didn't find  HystrixFeignClient annotation.

 But i just wanted to understand how putting HystrixCommand annotation on a method that calls method on a feignClient is different that using HystrixFeign ?

Answer (score -1):

please use semaphore isolation:

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          strategy: SEMAPHORE
```